# Setting default text box in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am currently creating a PPT template. Everything was smoothly processing till I tried to copy a manually created textbox from another PPT file.

The font size and color have been defined from the Slide master but when I copy paste manually created (inserted) textbox or the text in that box to my current working slide, the font size and color do not follow my theme formatting. For example, my theme color for content text is gray with 18pt Calibri size but instead copied text keep my theme formatting, it follows source formatting.

I am not sure how can I fix this problem. I hope I have stated my issue clearly.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the texts at first to Windows Notepad. From there copy the texts to your new textboxes. Check also, if paste special as text only option is available in your case in PowerPoint. Do not paste whole boxes, only the text.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply but this template is going to be used by many people like 400. So I am looking for a simple way of doing that instead using 3rd app.